# How to use Perl Storable, changing a hash value

Tags: perl, storable

I'm no Perl expert, so this is probably an easy question.

I've been using Storable, and following [this example](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html#EXAMPLES) to store a hash. First, I store the original hash.

```
use Storable qw(store retrieve freeze thaw dclone);
%color = ('Blue' => 1, 'Red' => 0.8, 'Black' => 0, 'White' => 1);
store(\%color, 'mycolors');
```

Then I retrieve it. (different script)

```
use Storable qw(store retrieve freeze thaw dclone);
$colref = retrieve('mycolors');
printf "Blue is still %lf\n", $colref->{'Blue'};
```

My question is how can I change one of the hash values? For example, do something like

```
$colref->{'Blue'} = 2;
store(\%color, 'mycolors');
```

in the second script.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @geekosaur Whenever I read it back, Blue (and all other colors) was now 0. I think that makes sense -- %color isn't defined in the read script, but I don't know how I should be pulling it from 'mycolors'

Comment: You have the right idea; consider what you already have, compared to what you want to pass to `store`.

Comment: @geekosaur I just tried store(\%colref, 'mycolors'); which resulted in the same thing. I'm kinda unfamiliar with perl syntax. Can you help me out?

Comment: @geekosaur Aaah, nevermind. Got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Needed to change

```
store(\%color, 'mycolors');
```

to

```
store($colref, 'mycolors');
```